# Can two nginx file affect each other?

Tags: nginx

Do two nginx configuration files operate independently to each other, or can they affect each other in some way?

For example, can I name the upstream block in two configuration files with the same name without causing a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean configuration files usually found in the **conf.d/** directory - no, they're not independent, because they're all included in the main **nginx.conf** and for **nginx** they all look like one big configuration file. They're separated just for administration convenience - it's easier to support multiple logically partitioned configuration than one big, messy file.

Comment: I mean the conf files under `sites-enabled/` directory. Is this what you thought I meant?

Comment: Yep, it's pretty much the same for them - they're all included in the main **nginx.conf** too, so they can affect each other.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask what else might potentially cross pollute the global setting beside the name for upstream?

Comment: Pretty much everything that's outside of *server { ... }* blocks.